# How to plot a marker on maps from the database

Tags: java, android, string, maps

I am new to Android Development as well as new to StackOveflow. Sorry if I am asking a repeated question.
I was making an app to fetch location coordinates from MySQL database and plot the markers on the map.
I am able to fetch the value into a textView.

```
String answer = "-32.430412,-58.321323,#-32.430412,-58.321323,#-32.430412,-58.321323,#";
```

It perfectly works when the co ordinates are entered in this way but does not work when the coordinates are fetched from the database.

```
String answer = json_string;
```

I am unable to find the solution to the problem. The app closes with a null pointer exception
This is my MapsActivity.java

```
public void getCoords(View view) {
    new CoordsBackgroundTask().execute();

}

class CoordsBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String json_url_coords;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        json_url_coords = "http://192.168.225.139/location_marker/just.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_url_coords);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING + "\n");
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewMaps);
        textview.setText(result);
        json_string = result;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json_string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    setUpMap();
}

public void Gpsconnection() {
    gps = new GPSCord(MapsActivity.this);
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Longitude:"+Double.toString(longitude)+"\nLatitude:"+Double.toString(latitude),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }

}


private void setUpMap() {
    String answer = "-32.430412,-58.321323,#-32.430412,-58.321323,#-32.430412,-58.321323,#";
    //String answer = json_string;
    String[] parts = answer.split("#");

    for (String point : parts) {
        String[] pointData = point.split(",");
        Float lat = Float.parseFloat(pointData[0]);
        Float lng = Float.parseFloat(pointData[1]);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                .title("Hello world"));


    }
}
```

And my PHP is as follows:

```
 <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "location_marker");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT markers.lat, markers.lng
FROM markers";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
/*
echo $row['lat'];
echo ',';
echo $row['lng'];
echo ',';
echo '#';
*/

}
echo '-32.430412,-58.321323,#-32.430412,-58.321323,#-32.430412,-58.321323,#';

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

I even tried the exact same result to confirm still there was a exception.

And the Exception looks like this:

```
    02-19 02:40:42.246 28422-28441/com.hexapixel.hexa I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 21
02-19 02:40:44.786 28422-28422/com.hexapixel.hexa D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-19 02:40:44.786 28422-28422/com.hexapixel.hexa W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x430f2140)
02-19 02:40:44.796 28422-28422/com.hexapixel.hexa E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.hexapixel.hexa, PID: 28422
                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3846)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3841)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478) 
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at com.hexapixel.hexa.MapsActivity.setUpMap(MapsActivity.java:193)
                                                                        at com.hexapixel.hexa.MapsActivity.getCoords(MapsActivity.java:62)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3841) 
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478) 
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So now I fixed the problem in app on kitkat rom but why is it now crashingg on Lollipop rom. Also could anyone give a link to understand all these crash logs myself.

Crash Log in Lollipop rom:

```
    02-21 00:34:59.509 19445-19552/com.hexapixel.hexa I/art: DexFile_isDexOptNeeded failed to open oat file '/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@data@com.google.android.gms@app_chimera@m@0000000d@GoogleCertificates_GmsCore_prodlmp_alldpi_release.apk@classes.dex' for file location '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000d/GoogleCertificates_GmsCore_prodlmp_alldpi_release.apk': Failed to open oat filename for reading: No such file or directory
02-21 00:35:00.769 19445-19445/com.hexapixel.hexa D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-21 00:35:00.769 19445-19445/com.hexapixel.hexa E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.hexapixel.hexa, PID: 19445
                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19761)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756) 
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19761) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
                                                                        at com.hexapixel.hexa.MapsActivity.setUpMap(MapsActivity.java:227)
                                                                        at com.hexapixel.hexa.MapsActivity.getCoords(MapsActivity.java:78)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002) 
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756) 
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19761) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

The new Program after applying SharedPreference which works in Kitkat but crashes in Lollipop and other Higher roms(Oreo).

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GPSCord gps;
    double longitude;
    double latitude;

    public String JSON_STRING;
    public String json_string;
    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    private static final String TAG = "Maps Activity check";




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        Gpsconnection();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yolla location traced \n Longitude:" + Double.toString(longitude) + "\nLatitude:" + Double.toString(latitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.


    }



    public void getCoords(View view) {
        new CoordsBackgroundTask().execute();

        setUpMap();
    }

    class CoordsBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        String json_url_coords;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            json_url_coords = "http://192.168.225.139/location_marker/just.php";
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(json_url_coords);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING + "\n");
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewMaps);
            textview.setText(result);
            json_string = result;


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("name", json_string);
            editor.commit();



        }

    }

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        //setUpMap();

        // marker information tab clicked...........

        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera

        LatLng loc1 = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc1).title("My Current Location").snippet("").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
        float zoomLevel = 16; //This goes up to 21
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc1, zoomLevel));

    }

    public void Gpsconnection() {
        gps = new GPSCord(MapsActivity.this);
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Longitude:"+Double.toString(longitude)+"\nLatitude:"+Double.toString(latitude),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }

    }


    private void setUpMap() {

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String answer = name;
        String[] parts = answer.split("#");

        for (String point : parts) {
            String[] pointData = point.split(",");
            Float lat = Float.parseFloat(pointData[0]);
            Float lng = Float.parseFloat(pointData[1]);
            String agencyName = pointData[2];
            String mainphoneNo = pointData[3];
            //String altphoneNo = pointData[4];

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                    .title(agencyName)
                    .snippet(mainphoneNo));

        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        String uri = "tel:" + marker.getSnippet();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could You add the crashlog from logcat when the null pointer exception occurs

Comment: I had edited the question to include the Logcat output.

Comment: Possibly you are running this on emulator with Google Services not installed.Try installing in real devices with google services installed.

Comment: Its on real Device... The map fragment does not open on emulator as there is no play service. I even tried with multiple devices...still crashes

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at com.hexapixel.hexa.MapsActivity.setUpMap(MapsActivity.java:193)
                                                                        at com.hexapixel.hexa.MapsActivity.getCoords(MapsActivity.java:62)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
                                                                        at com.hexapixel.hexa.MapsActivity.setUpMap(MapsActivity.java:227)
                                                                        at com.hexapixel.hexa.MapsActivity.getCoords(MapsActivity.java:78)

Comment: your stacktrace says the issue in your MapActivity.java file line 193, 62, 227, 78

Comment: Solved it. It was just an issue with butterKnife Bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually giving you null value. Network call happens in a separate thread. If it was in the same thread then the data would have retained. But in android if you do the network call on the UI thread then you will get an "App not responding" dialog. Now to retain data from network calls use `SharedPreferences`. It is the simplest way to store data and then retrieve later. You can also try using `StringBuffer`

Comment: Thank you very much its working perfectly now. It took me some time to learn about SharedPreferences and after which I could solve the problem. Thanks again...

Comment: You can use retrofit for network calls. its very simple and efficient. it has lots of features like logging and all. You can also integrate Stetho Network Interceptor with retrofit and okhttp. Just do a bit of research on stetho, retrofit, and okhttp. this will make a lot simpler in your future development.

Comment: Okay will do some research on it. I am still a newbie.

Comment: Btw.... What should i do with this question now ? Do i have to delete the question or i have to leave it ? I Don't know.

Comment: i was also a newbie 1year back. my seniors gave me those tricks. see video tutorials in youtube. you will be learning it a lot faster.

Comment: don't delete. all your questions will have impact on your stackoverflow user reputation.

Comment: So now I fixed the problem in app on kitkat rom but why is it now crashingg on Lollipop rom. Also could you give a link(tutorial) to understand all these crash logs myself. It would be a great help.

Comment: post the stacktrace here as an answer. Lets see why it's crashing.

Comment: post your entire java code. you might be having some initialization problem in google map

Comment: Edited Question the App works in KItkat but crashes in higher roms